# Commutative property for Hilbert-Schmidt norm?

Tags: inequality, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, trace, svd

Let $A,B$ be linear, compact, self-adjoint and even trace-class operators.

Can I bound $\|ABA^{-1}\|_{HS}$  by the norm of $\|B\|_{HS}$ somehow? (Where the bound does not depend on $\|A^{-1}\|$.)

Here $A^{-1}$  means the pseudo inverse i.e. for $$Af=\sum_{j}\lambda_j\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j$$ we set $A^{-1}$:
$$
A^{-1}f=\sum_{j}\lambda^{-1}_j\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j.
$$

Comment: thank you for your answer but for the bound i need to get rid of $A^{-1}$ unfortunatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general one cannot even guarantee that $ABA^{-1}$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator (or a bounded operator for that matter) as the following example will illustrate. Let
\begin{align*}
A&:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}|e_n\rangle\langle e_n|\\
B&:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{3/2}}\big(|e_n\rangle\langle e_{n+1}|+|e_{n+1}\rangle\langle e_{n}|\big)
\end{align*}
be operators on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ with $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ the standard basis. Obviously, $A$ is self-adjoint and trace class, and $B$ is self-adjoint. Let us quickly see that $B$ is also trace class; it [suffices to show that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1429856) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\langle\phi_n,B\phi_n\rangle|<\infty$ for all orthonormal bases $(\phi_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. Indeed, we compute
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\langle\phi_n,B\phi_n\rangle|&\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac1{p^{3/2}}\big|2\operatorname{Re}\big(\langle\phi_n,e_p\rangle\langle e_{p+1},\phi_n\rangle\big)\big|\\
&\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{p=1}^\infty 2\frac1{p^{3/2}}\big|\langle\phi_n,e_p\rangle\langle e_{p+1},\phi_n\rangle\big|\\
&=2\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac1{p^{3/2}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big|\langle\phi_n,e_p\rangle\langle e_{p+1},\phi_n\rangle\big|\\
&\leq 2\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac1{p^{3/2}}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big|\langle\phi_n,e_p\rangle|^2\Big)^{1/2}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle e_{p+1},\phi_n\rangle\big|\Big)^{1/2}=2\sum_{p=1}^\infty\frac1{p^{3/2}}\,.
\end{align*}
Here, in the second-to-last line we used [a version of Fubini's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89959) to interchange summation (because all summands are non-negative), and in the last line we used the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ as well as [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity#Generalization_of_the_Pythagorean_theorem) (because $\|e_p\|=1$).
But the upper bound we found is well known to converge so we showed that $B$ is trace class.

A straightforward *formal* computation shows
$$
ABA^{-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt n}|e_n\rangle\langle e_{n+1}|+\frac1{(n+1)n^{3/2}}|e_{n+1}\rangle\langle e_n|
$$
so
\begin{align*}
\|ABA^{-1}\|_\mathrm{HS}^2=\sum_{j,k=1}^\infty|\langle e_j,ABA^{-1}e_k\rangle|^2&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Big(\frac1{\sqrt n}\Big)^2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Big(\frac1{(n+1)n^{3/2}}\Big)^2\\
&=\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n}_{=\infty}+\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n+1)^2n^3}}_{<\infty}
\end{align*}
meaning that $ABA^{-1}$ is not a Hilbert-Schmidt operator ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/240842), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2736576)), although both $A,B$ are (even trace class).